# CR Oracle ODBC driver

Tags: crystal-reports

I have Crystal report 10 and need to connect to oracle db. Am looking for 
 CR Oracle ODBC driver. Where can i get it from.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install your ODBC driver in Windows by going to Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then **Data Sources (ODBC)**.

Click the **Add** button, and you should see *Microsoft ODBC for Oracle* as an available choice.  Installing this driver does require that you have the correct Oracle drivers installed first.  Once you have finished installing, Crystal Reports must be restarted to see the change.

Once these steps are completed you should have Oracle Database in your list of choices for an ODBC connection in CR.